# Firebase Cloud Messaging Push Notifications not working in Xcode project with multiple Targets

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications

So I have a single Xcode project for two iOS app targets that share a common codebase.

The first app was already working and live on the App Store. The second app is just a modified paid version of our earlier app.

Both the apps use  Firebase and OneSignal (for push notifications ) and I have downloaded two `GoogleServiceInfo.plist` files and linked them to their respective targets.

This is my `AppDelegate.swift` file where I configured Firebase.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var wakeTime : Date = Date() // when did our application wake up most recently?

    // To access AppDelegate  values
    class var shared: AppDelegate {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) ?? AppDelegate()
    }
        
    // To get token for login
    var pushRefreshedToken : String {
        print(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)
        return Messaging.messaging().fcmToken ?? "token_new_reg"
    }
    
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    var notification: Any?
    var window: UIWindow?
    //this variable is declared so that the app can run on ios 12 or lower running devices, without this it will show black screen.
    
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
      // time stamp the entering of foreground so we can tell how we got here
      wakeTime = Date()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        // OneSignal
        let notificationOpenedBlock: OSNotificationOpenedBlock = { result in
            
            // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
            let notification: OSNotification = result.notification
            print("Message: ", notification.body ?? "empty body")
            print("badge number: ", notification.badge)
            print("notification sound: ", notification.sound ?? "No sound")
                    
            if let additionalData = notification.additionalData {
                print("additionalData: ", additionalData)
                
                // Handle additional data
                switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
                    case .background, .inactive:
                        // background, opened from notif
                        if let tag = additionalData["t"] as? String {
                            if tag == NotificationRedirectionTags.appstore {
                                CentralLoadingViewController.redirectionTag = tag
                            } else {
                                MiddleViewController.notifTag = tag
                            }
                        }
                        
                    case .active:
                        // foreground
                        if let topVC = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
                            if let tag = additionalData["t"] as? String {
                                if tag == NotificationRedirectionTags.vehicleHealth {
                                    print("Going to VH")
                                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoards.CarHealthStoryboard, bundle: nil)
                                    let nv = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Identifiers.MainCarHealthViewController) as! MainCarHealthViewController
                                    topVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(nv, animated: true)
                                }
                                if tag == NotificationRedirectionTags.appstore {
                                    if let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/in/app/scouto/id1495648508") {
                                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    default:
                        break
                }
                
                // Handle action buttons
                if let actionSelected = notification.actionButtons {
                    print("actionSelected: ", actionSelected)
                }
                
                if let actionID = result.action.actionId {
                    //handle the action
                    if actionID == NotificationRedirectionTags.vehicleHealth {
                        MiddleViewController.notifTag = actionID
                    } else if actionID == NotificationRedirectionTags.appstore {
                        CentralLoadingViewController.redirectionTag = actionID
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(notificationOpenedBlock)
        
        // Remove this method to stop OneSignal Debugging
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE, visualLevel: .LL_NONE)

        // OneSignal initialization
        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        
        #if MAHINDRA_CW_PRODUCTION
        OneSignal.setAppId(appIDOne)
        #elseif SCOUTO_PRODUCTION
        OneSignal.setAppId(appIDTwo)
        #endif

        // promptForPushNotifications will show the native iOS notification permission prompt.
        // We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission (See step 8)
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
            print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
        })
        
        let str = [NotificationRedirectionTags.appstore, "AppStore"]
        if str.contains(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: NotificationActionTags.inputText) as? String ?? ""){
            if let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/in/app/scouto/id1495648508") {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            }
        }
 
        LocationService.shared.updatingLocation(completion: {  location in
            if location != nil{
                LocationService.shared.stopUpdatingLocation()
            } else {
                LocationService.shared.showLocationPermissionsAlert(true)
            }
        })
        
        // FireBase Setup
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // notification
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions) { (granted, error) in
                
                guard granted else { return }
                
                print("UNNotificationCenter Auth Granted")
                
                let replyAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "ReplyAction", title: "Reply", options: [])
                let openAppAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "OpenAppAction", title: "Open app", options: [.foreground])
                let quickReplyCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "QuickReply", actions: [replyAction, openAppAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([quickReplyCategory])
                
                print("UNNotificationCategory Set")

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                    guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
          } else if let token = token {
            print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
            //self.fcmRegTokenMessage.text  = "Remote FCM registration token: \(token)"
          }
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
    }

//MARK:- Push Notifications
extension AppDelegate {
        
    
    // DEPRECATED
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
                
        // Print full message.
        print("Remote notification: User info 1")
        print(userInfo)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print("User info 2")
        print(userInfo)
    
        //completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    
}

// MARK:- Push Notification Handler - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print("User info 3")
        print(userInfo)
            
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([[.alert, .badge , .sound]])
    }
    
    // Notification handler
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print full message.
        print("User info 4")
        print( )
        
        // Handle text input notification
        if response.actionIdentifier == "ReplyAction" {
            
            print("Entered ReplyAction block")

            if let textResponse = response as? UNTextInputNotificationResponse {
                // Do whatever you like with user text response...
                
                print("----RECEIVING USER NOTIFICATION INPUT ------")
                print(textResponse.userText)
                
                if textResponse.userText == NotificationRedirectionTags.appstore || textResponse.userText == "AppStore" {
                    if let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/in/app/scouto/id1495648508") {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    }
                }
                
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(textResponse.userText, forKey: NotificationActionTags.inputText)
                
                return
            }
        }
        
        // Handle userInfo data
        switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
            case .background, .inactive:
                // background, opened from notif
                if let tag = userInfo["t"] as? String {
                    if tag == NotificationRedirectionTags.appstore {
                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(tag, forKey: NotificationActionTags.inputText)
                    }
                    MiddleViewController.notifTag = tag
                }
                
            case .active:
                // foreground
                if let topVC = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
                    if let tag = userInfo["t"] as? String {
                        
                        // Go to Vehicle Health
                        if tag == NotificationRedirectionTags.vehicleHealth {
                            print("Going to VH")
                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoards.CarHealthStoryboard, bundle: nil)
                            let nv = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Identifiers.MainCarHealthViewController) as! MainCarHealthViewController
                            topVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(nv, animated: true)
                        }
                        
                        // Go to Live Track
                        if tag == "os" {
                            print("Going to Live Track")
                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoards.DashboardStoryboard, bundle: nil)
                            let nv = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Identifiers.LiveTrackingViewController) as! LiveTrackingViewController
                            topVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(nv, animated: true)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            default:
                break
        }
        
        
        completionHandler()
    }
}

//MARK: MessagingDelegate FCM -> Recieve message from FCM
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        
        let lokenFCM : String  = fcmToken ?? "token_new_reg"
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": lokenFCM]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    
//    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
//        print("Message message data", remoteMessage.appData)
//    }
}
```

I have uploaded the same APNS key to Firebase for both the apps in Project settings.

However, the issue is that I am able to receive notifications only on one app and I am not able to receive notifications in the second app.

I have checked the code multiple times but cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong at all.

Please kindly have a look at the code and provide me with some suggestions on what I may be doing wrong. Your help is highly appreciated & thank you!

Comment: Is that all you have under AppDelegate?

Comment: Nope. I just kept the parts related to notifications in here.